# How to Use the Filter "sidebar_login_widget_form_args"

Tags: plugins, filters, login, forms, sidebar

I need to rename some of the labels on the Sidebar Login form using the sidebar_login_widget_form_args" filter; I have been trying few days to do this without any success.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right directions.

Specifically, I need to rename the "Login->" button to just "Log In", rename the "Username" to "Username:" and "Password" to "Password:"

Here's my code which doesn't work:

```
/* Sidebar Login Plugin - Change Form Labels
add_filter( 'sidebar_login_widget_form_args','my_sidebar_login_widget_form_args', 10, 2);
function my_sidebar_login_widget_form_args() {

if ( 'label_username' === 'Username' ) { return 'Username:'; }// Change Username Label
if ( 'label_password' === 'Password' ) { return 'Password:'; }// Change Password Label
if ( 'label_log_in' === 'Login &rarr;' ) { return 'Log In'; } // Change Login Button Label
}
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: All of your code snippet is currently commented out by never closed comment at start. If your actual code is like that - that would render it useless indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to check again how to use WordPress filter. On your code, you haven't used the variable what `sidebar_login_widget_form_args` will pass to your function as argument. Please check below -

```
/* Sidebar Login Plugin - Change Form Labels */
add_filter( 'sidebar_login_widget_form_args','my_sidebar_login_widget_form_args', 10, 2);
function my_sidebar_login_widget_form_args( $args ) {
    // this is how you will change the argument values, using key
    $args['label_username'] = 'My Username'; // Change Username Label
    $args['label_password'] = 'My Pass'; // Change Password Label
    $args['label_log_in'] = 'My Log In'; // Change Login Button Label

    // after filter is done, you will return it
    return $args;
}
```

And make sure, your first line opening comment tag has a closing. Check the difference of my line and yours.